# Numerical Method for KdV travelling waves

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, fluid-dynamics

Can someone please direct me to the best NUMERICAL method or some references for solving
$$-cu_x + uu_x + u_{xxx} = 0$$
with periodic boundary conditions. This governs travelling waves of the KdV equation with speed $c$. I assume that I should be using some iteration method, but I'm not sure which will give me non-trivial solutions (solitons, cnoidal waves). Thanks :)

Comment: Probanly, there is a typo in $cu_x+uu_x+u_{xxx}=0$. Isn't it : $$cu_t+uu_x+u_{xxx}=0$$

Comment: @JJacquelin, nope the question is what i wanted to say. The KdV is $$u_t + uu_x + u_{xxx} = 0,$$ then seeking travelling wave solutions $u = u(x - ct)$, equivalently moving into a traveling frame and seeking steady solutions results in the above equation

Comment: OK, I understand your point.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer to the question about numerical method. Nevertheless, the result below can be numericaly evaluated in order to compare to the direct numerical methods.

$$-cu_x+uu_x+u_{xxx}=0=(u-c)u_x+u_{xxx}$$
This is an ODE of the autonomous kind. The usual change of function is :

$u_x=f(u) \quad\to\quad u_{xx}=f'f \quad\to\quad u_{xxx}=f''f^2+f'^2f$

$(u-c)u_x+u_{xxx}=0=(u-c)f+f''f^2+f'^2f=0$

$$(u-c)+f''f+f'^2=0=(u-c)+(f'f)'$$
$$(u^2-2cu+c_1)+2f'f=0$$
$$(\frac{1}{3}u^3-cu^2+c_1u+c_2)+f^2=0$$
$$f(u)=\pm\sqrt{-\frac{1}{3}u^3+cu^2-c_1u-c_2}=u_x$$
$$x=\pm\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{-\frac{1}{3}u^3+cu^2-c_1u-c_2}}$$
$x(u)$ is an elliptic function of $u$.

At this point, the constants $c_1$ and $c_2$ have to be determined according to the boundary conditions.

Inverting the function $x(u)$ in order to analytically express $u(x)$ might be more or less complicated, depending on $c_1$ and $c_2$. It might be impossible without convenient special functions. In practice, it isn't worthwhile since all ends with numerical calculus : the direct numerical integration of $\int \frac{du}{\sqrt{-\frac{1}{3}u^3+cu^2-c_1u-c_2}}$ allows all further computations.

Comment: I'm looking at a related problem, so I'm more concerned in numerics other than analytical solutions, since the above does not work for my related problem.

Comment: I well understand. My answer was adressed to those more interrested in analytic calculus.